# Alter commerce price field during feedme import

Tags: plugin-feedme, commerce4

I'm importing Craft Commerce products from a third party feed using the FeedMe plugin and I would like to change the formatting/data of the price field.

The API is providing the price as cents and I need it to be a number in euro.
Eg. 1535 -> 15.35

I've made a module using the `EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE` event but can't figure out how to change the price. The same code works if I want to change the slug.

This is what I have in my module and doesn't work. (A test to set the price of all products to 10)

```
Event::on(
   Process::class, 
   Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE,
      function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
         $element = $event->element;
        
         if ($element instanceof \craft\commerce\elements\Product) {
            $element->defaultVariant->price = 10;
            }            
      });
```

This test, to change al the slugs to `Test`, does work.

```
Event::on(
   Process::class, 
   Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE,
      function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
         $element = $event->element;
        
         if ($element instanceof \craft\commerce\elements\Product) {
            $element->slug = "Test";
            }            
      });
```

Anyone has any idea how to alter the price of a commerce product during import?